# li menu hide behind when dropopen to select item

Tags: html, css

When open dropdown to select an item and at the same time hover mouse of Dropdown it's submenu hide behind dropdownlist.Below is sample code.Please ref attached image for issue.[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
<br>
<select><option>test doc1</option><option>test doc1</option><option>test doc1</option></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Select Drop Down Option Z-index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210725/html-select-drop-down-option-z-index)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make div go behind another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561585/how-to-make-div-go-behind-another-div)

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your style :

```
.dropdown:hover ~ select:focus{
      display:none;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make sure that the dropdown is over the dropdown list. You can do this by adding z-index to the .dropbox-content that looks like this:

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 999;  <--- Added
}
```